# How to store red bean paste?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime

I've bought some red bean paste to use to fill mochi. I don't think I'll use it all in one go and I'm not able to translate what the package says for how to store it.

What is the best way to store it once the package is opened and how long will it last for?

(This is the paste I am using: http://www.japancentre.com/items/maeda-hokkaido-red-bean-paste-koshian)

Many thanks :)

Comment: As a fermented bean product, I suspect it will last an extremely long time if you freeze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fermented bean paste, it should last for weeks in an airtight container in the fridge. For best results, make sure to leave as little head room (for air) as possible in the container.

To be honest, when I store Miso (for example), I just squeeze the air out and put a clip on the bag it came in, and then leave it in the fridge.

If you need longer storage than several weeks, you can probably freeze it, though at that point you might want to consider buying smaller packages.

Answer (score 1):

take the rest of the paste out of the bag, and wrap it with some cling film, then put it into a container. I use this method to store that kind of paste for weeks, and still ok.